# HERE-lite API - custom line style

Tags: android, here-api

I'd like to draw a line between two lat/lng locations in the HERE-lite mapView for Android. Of course, there would be the PolyLine object, but this object only provides styling options like color or stroke width.

How would I draw a line with extended styling options, like dashed or dotted lines similar to the Canvas/Paint object?

Thanks for advice
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet possible with the *Lite edition*. However, you may want to consider to switch to the [HERE SDK for Android (Explore Edition)](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.6.2.0/dev_guide/index.html), as it supports custom line styling with different [DashPatterns](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.6.2.0/api_reference/content/com/here/sdk/mapview/MapPolyline.html#getDashPattern--).